# JavaScript: Open a ui.bootstrap modal inside a plotly_click event in a plotly.js plot

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap, plotly.js

I am developing a web server using an AngularJS framework. In this server I am creating interactive plots, so that when the user clicks the plot curves a modal window appears. These plots are created in plotly.js and the modal windows are created using the directive `ui.bootstrap.modal`. Then, when the user clicks the plot, a `plotly_click` event containing the function to show the modal is called.

The problem is that the modal only appears the first time you click on the plot. Afterwards, if you close or dismiss the modal, when you click the plot again no modal window appears. From the console I can see that the function that creates the modal it's being executed properly. If I call the function that creates the modal window from outside the `plotly_click` event, everything works fine.

All this makes me think that the function creating the modals is fine.  Then, I think that the problem is within the plotly.js code or in the interaction between `plotly` and the `ui.bootstrap.modal` directive.

This is a simplification of my plotly.js code. I will not include how do I create the data for the sake of clarity:

```
var create_plot = function() {
    var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    // Define the data, annotations and layout that the plot will have //
    var data_list = [...];
    var annotations = [...];
    var layout = [...];
    var config = {
      "scrollZoom": true
    }
    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data_list, layout, config);
    myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data) {
        // This code will be executed when clicking in the plot //
        var j = data.points['0'].data.name.split(" ")[data.points['0'].data.name.split(" ").length - 1]
        $scope.showModal($scope.data.clusters[j])
      }
    };
```

And here is the function `showModal`, that creates the modal window:

```
$scope.showModal = function(cluster_data) {
  $scope.input_data = cluster_data
  $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
    animation: true,
    ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
    ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
    templateUrl: './views/popup_templates/scan_modal.html',
    windowClass: 'large-modal-window',
    scope: $scope,
    bindToController: true,
    controller: 'd2pResultController', // POP-UPS will be ruled by the same controller as the whole html
    size: 'lg',
  });
}
```

Does anybody have an idea of what can be going wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this inside $scope.$apply since the event not controlled by angular.

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
     $scope.showModal($scope.data.clusters[j])
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Axr! But the error still goes on.

Comment: make a plunker, not much anyone can help without seeing this in action. There could be a unrelated issue.